# Using jQuery deferred and promise inside loop

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred, object-literal

This is what i am trying to achieve,

I have a sorted array which i pass to jQuery each. Inside each there is an ajax call which will fetch me the desired data and every time push into another array(lets call it allJsonData). Finally i display allJsonData.
Problem is whenever i display allJsonData, elements are always displayed inconsistently (not alphabetically/random order). I am expecting allJsonData to be displayed alphabetically (that is AList data first, BList data second, CList data third and so on). 
I am new to jQuery deferred and promise. Thanks in advance.

```
var sortedArray = [AList, BList, CList, DList];
var promises = [];
var allJsonData = [];
$.each(sortedArray, function (index, value) {
var dfd = $.Deferred();
var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl  + ('/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle(' + "'" + value + "'" + ')/Items? + "SomeFilterParameters";

//AJAX CALL HERE//
.done(
  function (approvedListItems) {
    if (approvedListItems.d.results.length != 0) {
      $.each(approvedListItems.d.results, function (i, col) {
        allJsonData.push(col);//Push into master array
      });
    }//If closed
    dfd.resolve(allJsonData);
  }
);//Done closed
  promises.push(dfd);
});//jQuery Each closed
return $.when.apply($, promises).promise();
```

/****AJAX CALL****/

```
getListItems: function(url) {       
  var dfd = $.Deferred();
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: "GET",
      headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
      },
    success: function (data) {
      dfd.resolve(data);
    },
    error: function (error) {
      dfd.reject(sender, args, "Error retrieving items");
    }
  });
  return dfd.promise();         
},
```

Comment: ajax calls are async..hence the one which is called first may take  longer time while the third request is completed and pushed to array...hence the irregularity in the order of array......

Comment: you could just sort the allJsonData  in the done

Comment: Please show us the actual Ajax call.  To offer you the best answer, we need to see that part of the code too.

Comment: @RohitasBehera yes we can sort allJsonData but for time being i am avoiding it as it is again json array of objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do something as simple as this:

```
var sortedArray = [AList, BList, CList, DList];

Promise.all(sortedArray.map(function(value) {
    var url = ...;
    return getListItems(url);
})).then(function(results) {
    // results is an array of results from AList, BList, CList, DList in order
    let allJsonData = [];
    results.forEach(function(approvedListItems) {
        allJsonData.push.apply(allJsonData, approvedListItems.d.results);
    });
    // process allJsonData here
});

// simplify getListItems like this
getListItems: function(url) {       
    return $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        }
    });
},
```

The general idea here is that you get a raw list (without processing the sub-results inside of it) for each of the items in sortedArray.  Using either `Promise.all()` or `$.when()`, you will get the raw lists in order.  Then, after you have all the raw lists, you can process them in order and build your allJsonData structure in order.

Also, you can remove the promise anti-pattern from `getListItems()`.  `$.ajax()` already returns a promise so there is no need to wrap it in another promise.

You could convert this to use `$.when()` instead of `Promise.all()` if you really wanted to, but it is more complicated to use `$.when()` because of how it takes arguments and returns results.

Also, there's something wrong with the Javascript string syntax in your `url` variable.  I don't know what you intended to do there so I'm not sure what to suggest, but you need to fix that too.

Comment: Thanks a ton jfriend00. Its working as expected. It would be really helpful if you guide me with some good articles/links related to deferred and promise.

Comment: @Sid - You can start reading here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise.  There are a lot of good articles on promises you can find with Google.  If this answered your question, you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer and that will also earn you some reputation points here for following the proper procedure.